# Prove that $(3/2)^n\bmod 1\equiv (2^n-1)/2^n $ has infinitely many solutions as $n \to\infty$

Tags: limits, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, fractional-part, modular-function

The first part of the question is false and was proved by the answer vefore. The second part of the question asks to prove  that $(3/2)^n \bmod 1\equiv (2^n-1)/2^n$ also has infinite solutions as $n \to\infty$.

Comment: What does "Prove that $(3/2)^n \equiv 1/2^n \mod 1$ has infinite solutions as $n \to\infty$" mean? Do you just mean, "Prove that $(3/2)^n \equiv 1/2^n\mod 1$ has infinitely many solutions ?"

Comment: Are the $n$s on the two sides supposed to be the same? Your example of $n=5$ should be $n=4$

Comment: Also, where did the question come from? It seems quite difficult, and to me it isn't intuitive that the result should be true. What makes it intuitive to you?

Comment: Presumably this is the same question as the less confusing "Prove that there are infinitely many integers $n$ such that $3^n\equiv 1\pmod{2^n}$".

Comment: Please don't rely on the title of your MSE questions for important information: make the body self-contained. As for the mathematics here, I have no idea what your are talking about: is $n$ the value we are trying to solve for, or what?

Comment: Alternatively this is is also another way of stating the question: There are infinitely many natural $n$ where $(\frac 32)^n-(\frac 12)^n$ is an integer.  (Presumably.... the question of what does "infinite solutions as $n\to \infty$" means, is still unclear.)

Comment: You shouldn't say "infinite solutions" if you mean infinitely many solutions. If you have two solutions, each of which is an "infinite solution" (whatever that means) then you have infinite solutions, but not infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Infinitely many solutions is correct.

Comment: This seems unlikely to be true.  Heuristically, the probability that $3^n$ is equal to $1$ (mod $2^n$) is $1/2^n$, so the expected number of solutions is only $1$.  And in practice only $n=1,2,4$ appear to be solutions.

Comment: if there is a finite number of solutions then it implies that as $n \to\infty$ after a certain integer  this will never occur again. Heuristically, the probability. cannot be $1/2^$  because even numbers are never part of the numerator.

Comment: Please do not change your question after someone has answered the original question.

Answer (score 5):

This is not true. A result of Beukers from 1981 (combined with a tiny amount of computation) implies that
$$
\| (3/2)^k \| > 2^{-0.9k},
$$
for all $k \geq 5$. Here $\|x\|$ denotes the distance from a real number $x$ to the nearest integer.

Comment: Thank. you. So is the second part true and if yes is there a proof? By the way, do you have a link to Beuker's work?

Comment: This answers your second question as well....

Comment: Please can someone link a resource for this result?

Comment: @Adam See this paper by Habsieger (for explicit computations) and references inside (downloadable pdf at the link): https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Explicit-lower-bounds-for-%24%5C%7C%283%2F2%29%5Ek%5C%7C%24-Habsieger/bb4db922d7a5785494f9d6d9fb1ad9116c93763c

Comment: @Conrad thank you.

Comment: @Adam Happy to be of help

Answer (score 2):

You can prove by induction that if $n$ is even and is exactly divisible by $2^k$ then

$$3^n \equiv 1 + 2^{k+2} \bmod 2^{k+3}$$

Whereas if $n$ is odd then

$$3^n \equiv 3 \bmod 2^3$$

If $n \ge 6$, then $n \ge \log_2(n) + 3 \ge k + 3 \ge 3$ and hence the congruence can never hold; one doesn’t need anything as sophisticated as Beuker’s result.